# What should we do with manuals from the 80s?

Tags: documentation

I have access to several meters of manuals of various sorts around CP/M on PCs and various bits on mainframes. These are earmarked to go after decades of "cannot dump that" heartbleed. Most are originals, but also many copies. I helped to put some on eBay but nobody wanted them. What should I do?

Is there a postal address to which we can send several parcels?

Edit: Thank you for the suggestions. The problems with those have also been raised. The folks with these kinds of manuals in their attic/cellar are unlikely to happily invest a couple of 1000s of $/€/whatever to get those digitized. Skimming through those manuals one easily recognizes the cores/seeds of today's technologies, also the introductions are nice. But most striking are the touch and feel of some excellent quality folders, typically. Some come with leather. Others just just feel rock solid with nice colors and have wonderful separators for the chapters throwing your antique favorite technical keywords at you. You don't kill them, being digital or not. And I am afraid I would be in trouble for putting them up as  a piece of craft and decoration at our place - but that is what they (often) are - both your mind and for your physical habitat.

Comment: Look at the list at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_museums if you have a museum nearby. In that case, contact them and ask if they are interested. Some of them scans old documents to make sure they are preserved.

Comment: You should save them. Punch cards are coming back, you know. This "USB drive" stuff is just a passing fad. :-)

Comment: The more pressing question: How to protect yourself from frivolous copyright infrigement harassment?

Comment: Monitor stands?

Comment: You mean, assault any complainant with a monitor stand?

Comment: @ChrisBouchard I'm already using old academic journals for monitor stands: my monitor doesn't need to be any higher!

Answer (score 45):

You could have a look on [bitsavers.org](http://bitsavers.org). They catalogue and preserve computer manuals. If you have any unique manuals which are not yet catalogued on there, I am sure they would accept a scanned copy, but not in the form of dead trees.

Comment: "I have a VERY large backlog of material to scan and don't actively sollicit material to work on." says the web page.

Comment: @snips-n-snails To clarify (I hope), Bitsavers is not actively soliciting _paper items to scan_. I think they'll still accept and archive PDFs. I contributed a scanned manual there as recently as 2015.

Answer (score 32):

First, check if the documents aren't already present on Bitsavers and Archive.org.
If you do have something unique that hasn't been scanned yet, you can maybe try the new initiative [announced today](https://twitter.com/textfiles/status/1161700352045064192) by [Jason Scott aka @texfiles](https://twitter.com/textfiles):

> Announcing SCANTASTIX, a project that  [@KevinSavetz](https://twitter.com/KevinSavetz)  and I have
> whipped up to go after a class of what I call "Unadvocated Materials"
> and can be summarized as "If you have a few extra bucks, you can
> ensure neat stuff gets scanned and put on the Internet Archive".
>
> ...
>
> If you saw how we did the Ted Nelson Junk Mail project, this would be
> similar. We take boxes of material, loose or bound, and scan it into
> digital form and store away the originals.

Alternatively, you can try a service like [1dollarscan.com](http://1dollarscan.com/pricing.php) (there may be others)

Comment: I wonder how can 1dollarscan afford to provide scanning so cheap. Are there machines that scan books automatically? I cannot imagine a system that could turn pages of various books without many errors.

Comment: @TomášZato Cut off the back and it's just a stack of paper. Hope it doesn't get stuck in the stack-scanner and there you go, 1 dollar.

Comment: @TomášZato I assume they cut off the spine and use sheet fed scanners (IIRC they mention somewhere that the books are destroyed during scanning). Note that the low price applies only to books with ISBN (probably they use it to not scan the same book twice); other materials are more expensive.

Comment: @TomášZato if you have money there’s also this: https://www.treventus.com/automatic-book-scanner-scanrobot.html

Comment: Here's a little bit about how [Google does it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Books#Scanning_of_books).

Answer (score 10):

I'd get a nice sheetfed document scanner, [cut off the spines](https://forum.diybookscanner.org/viewtopic.php?t=1278), and feed in the manuals one at a time. Then upload to [archive.org](http://archive.org).

Comment: The Internet Archive has services where you can donate books to them for them to scan.

Comment: If you can find a proper industrial [guillotine paper cutter](https://www.mccunecollection.org/Challenge%20Advance%20Guillotine%20Paper%20Cutter) (perhaps not as old as that one) you'll get a very clean cut and need not even remove the covers yourself. Most print shops that do binding will have one.

Comment: It's also not appreciated how difficult this actually is. It's a real hassle. A "nice sheetfeed document scanner" is not cheap. The local photocopy store charges more to scan documents than it does to copy them (over twice as much), and scanning can just flat out be finicky with jams, double feeds, etc. Add that to the idea of doing 1000's of pages and the headache adds up.

Comment: I've not checked scanning prices at the copy shop lately, but almost all business-level photocopier/printer units these days will do scanning just as easily. If it's expensive at a copy shop, consider finding someone who works in an office with one of these and asking him to run the cut sheets through. It's no different from a photocopying job except that no paper is used.

Answer (score 7):

Your options seem to be:

- Donating them to a local or non-local museum
- Donating them to [The Internet Archive](https://archive.org) or [Bitsavers](https://bitsavers.org)
- [Digitizing them yourself](https://www.diybookscanner.org/) (Stack Exchange thread [here](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/13487/how-would-one-digitize-a-thick-book-into-a-pdf-version-in-the-most-time-efficien))
- Posting to a special interest mailing list (perhaps [CCTalk](http://classiccmp.org/lists.html) or one of the lists [here](http://planetmvs.com/links/news.html)))

Additionally I'm sure that if you posted to the [SDF bulletin board](https://sdf.org/?tutorials/bboard-tutorial) or somewhere on the [tildes network](http://tilde.club/~pfhawkins/othertildes.html) that someone there would definitely be interested.

Comment: "Do nothing." and "Bin them." are also options.

Comment: @VinceO'Sullivan **no**!